# How to send fetch api request with object parameter with Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, fetch-api

I try to send a user object in json format to backend and I get username, password, email etc. at backend from the parameter.
Here is my backend code:

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public User loginUser(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
        User userObj = null;
        if (!isNull(user.getEmail()) && !isNull(user.getPassword())) {
            userObj = userService.getUserByEmailAndPassword(user);
        }
        if (isNull(userObj)) {
            throw new Exception("Bad credentials");
        }
        return userObj;
    }
```

As you see I am not sending string parameters, I am sending the whole object.

In frontend,
my component code is:

```
async loginUser(user:User) {
   let response = await this._service.LoginUser(user);
   let data = response.json();
   console.log(data);
 }
```

and this code is calling the following method from the service class,

```
LoginUser(user: User) {
    var url = new URL"http://localhost:8080/login");
    var params =[[user]];
    url.search = new URLSearchParams(user).toString;
    return fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", user)
  }
```

But there is something wrong about sending request with parameter **user**. How can I make this request?(without using Jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch()` by default, sends a `GET` request and you don't need to pass a second argument to `fetch` when making a `GET` request.

If you want to pass user data in URL using query parameters, you will need to pass the URL with query string to `fetch` as the only argument

```
LoginUser(user: User) {
    var url = new URL"http://localhost:8080/login");
    url.search = new URLSearchParams(user);
    return fetch(url.toString());
}
```

If you are trying to log user in, **DON'T** pass user authentication data in the URL. Instead make a `POST` request.

In order to send a `POST` request, you need to pass a second argument to `fetch()` which is an object containing different properties representing various request options.

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(user)
}
```

For details on `Fetch API`, see [MDN - Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am getting "415 Unsupported Media Type" error and the request is not even coming to backend. Should I modify something on backend ?

Comment: 415 error code indicates that the server refused to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format. Check in the Network tab in Developer tools if you are sending the data in the format that backend expects.

Answer (score 2):

```
@PostMapping("/login")
```

You defined your `login` endpoint as a `POST` method so you have to call fetch with `POST` method.

```
LoginUser(user: User) {
  return fetch("http://localhost:8080/login", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
  });
}
```

Note: If you are using Angular 2+ as you stated in your title, then it's best to use Angular's built-in HttpClient(https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) module.